# Pass in functions to a helper method

Tags: function, loops, go

Is it possible in Go to iterate over a set of functions?

I have this helper method in my unit test file:

```golang
func helper(t *testing.T, f func(string) bool, stringArray []string, expected bool) {
    for _, input := range stringArray {
        if f(input) != expected {
            t.Errorf("Expected '%v' for string: %v", !expected, input)
        }

    }
}
```

Instead of doing copy/paste of a line and changing the 2nd peramiter like this ugliness:

```
func Test_isUnique(t *testing.T) {
    var valid = []string{"", "b", "ab", "acd", "asdfjkl", "aA"}
    var invalid = []string{"aa", "avva", "aaa", "asdfweryhfda", "asdfjkal"}
    helper(t, funcA, valid, true)
    helper(t, funcB, invalid, false)
    helper(t, funcC, valid, true)
    helper(t, funcD, invalid, false)
    helper(t, funcE, valid, true)
    helper(t, funcF, invalid, false)
    helper(t, funcG, valid, true)
    helper(t, funcH, invalid, false)
}
```

I am instead wondering if there is a for option here to reduce this to a 4 line body function

```
  for f in [funcA, funcB, funcB, funcC, funcD, etc]: // Fix this
    helper(t, f, valid, true)
    helper(t, f, invalid, false)
```

Forgive the mix of python/go above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. E.g. you can range over any slices, including those whose element type is a function type. Just put your functions into a slice:

```
fs := []func(string) bool{funcA, funcB, funcC, funcD, ...}

for _, f := range fs {
    helper(t, f, valid, true)
    helper(t, f, invalid, false)
}
```

Also for what you're trying to achieve, table driven tests might be more suitable. Please check [Go Wiki: Table Driven Tests](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/TableDrivenTests), and also [The Go Blog: Using Subtests and Sub-benchmarks](https://blog.golang.org/subtests).

Comment: Thanks. Found this can also be nested within the range block and not needing to declare a variable.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic go way would be to use table driven tests:

```golang
func TestMyFunction(t *testing.T) {
  valid := []string{"", "b", "ab", "acd", "asdfjkl", "aA"}
  cases := []struct{
    name string,
    f func(string) bool
    input []string
    expected bool
  }{
    {
       "Test func a",
       funcA,
       valid,
       true
    },
    // Other test cases
  }

  for _, tc := range cases {
      t.Run(tc.name, func(t *testing.T) {
          helper(t, tc.func, tc.input, tc.expected)
      })
  }
}
```

As a side note: You can actually explicitly mark helper functions using the [Helper](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T.Helper) function. This ensures that your helper function is excluded from the line information printed when running tests:

```golang
func helper(t *testing.T) {
  t.Helper()
  // Helper function code
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So this is what the vscode auto-generated stub was for. I found it a bit too much but if it's the norm in Go then I better get used to it :)

Comment: I just noticed the problem above is that the subTests don't run on each element in valid but rather it only runs for each 'test case' above. Getting the feeling that either the valid array should be removed and create a 'test case' for each element or alternatively the subtest should be placed in my helper method to do the iteration over my valid elements. What is the correct way to do this in Go?

Comment: Yeah each test case now indeed checks one array. It really depends on what the function is doing. Given that the function takes in a string I suggest going for the single element approach.